# Prisma Select with a Some with And then OR

Tags: select, prisma

Running into an issue I can do with left Joins but not seeing it in Prisma.

I have a 1 to many relation with geo locations to either allow or not allow.  the table is as follows
table restrictions :

```
Item | Geo | Allow
```

So if i have an item that is allowed in the US I would have

```
1   |  US  | 1
1   |  DE  | 1
```

Or I could have to also allow US

```
1   | GB  | 0
1   | CA  | 0
```

with the allow 1 that means any values with 1 are allowed, if the there is a 0 then only the listed items are allowed, if I look at geo of customer country I want to select only items allowed for that geo.

with SQL I can do a left join for each

and select in the where, in Prisma I see it like this but cant get it into the code

```
where: {
  type : 'active',
  restrictions: {
    some: {
      geo: "US",
      allow: 1,
    },
  },
},
```

this I assume with be geo is US AND allow is 1, I also need to do an OR geo is not US and geos that are associated with id are allow 0

I would also need to add an OR to say if some do not contain 'US' and allow is 0 (all relations to an item are either all allow = 0 or allow =1 )

So I need this.
NOT: {restrictions: { some: { country: 'US', allow: 1 } },},
restrictions: { some: { country: 'US', allow: 1 } },

Update here is the working solution, I misunderstood the OR [{ }, { }];

```
where: {
      type: "active",
      OR: [
        {
          NOT: { restrictions: { some: { country: "US", allow: 0 } } },
        },
        {
          restrictions: { some: { allow: 1, country: not: "us" } }, 
        },
      ],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely misunderstood the syntax of OR, here is the simple solution

```
where: {
      type: "active",
      OR: [
        {
          NOT: { restrictions: { some: { country: "US", allow: 0 } } },
        },
        {
          restrictions: { some: { allow: 1, country: "US" } },
        },
      ],
    },
```